# how can i add item inside listview. widget items ? how can i add item inside listview. widget items. I want to add an item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv3XL.png)

> how can i add item inside listview. widget items ?
> how can i add item inside listview. widget items. I want to add an item in the form of a container wrapped in inkwell with the exact same size as the listview

```
    return PageView(
  controller: controller,
  children: List.generate(cake.length + 1, (index) {
    final cakeData = cake[index];
    if (cake[index] == cake.length) {
      return Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('add')
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: _list.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == _list.length) {
              return Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              );
            }
          }),
    )
```

[image]

**Edit:**
in your case you should do this:

```
PageView(
      children: List.generate(cake.length + 1, (index) {
        if (index == cake.length) {
          return Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        } else {
          final cakeData = cake[index];
          return ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [Text('add')],
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      }),
    )
```

Comment: i applied it to the pageview and it throws this kind of error RangeError(RangeError(index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0). @eamirho3ein

Comment: could add your full snippet code ?so I could see what did you do so far?

Comment: I've added my code @eamirho3ein

Comment: it works, but if i add next and prev button it doesn't work, it means the next button will disappear before it reaches the add button @eamirho3ein

Comment: you mean you want to see more than one item in every scroll?

Comment: page view meant to show one item in every scroll but if you want to create what you show in question with  pageView's scrollBehavior, you should use listview with custom scrollphysics.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.builder` with horizontal scrolling

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 4,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```